# Ethernet over USB stopped working: Cannot find device USB0

Tags: linux, networking, ifconfig

I used Ethernet over USB for some years to connect from my Debian 8 workstation to a Linux device with `g_multi` running. Today it stopped working, although (everybody says that) "I didn't touch anything".

What I know:

- The device is okay (Ethernet over usb is fine on another machine)
- USB port and cable is okay (mass storage from the device is still mounted)
- `lsmod` lists `usbnet`, `rndis_host`, `rndis_wlan` and `cdc_ether`, as expected
- `/etc/network/interfaces` still reads: `

  ```
  allow-hotplug usb0
  auto usb0
  iface usb0 inet static
      address 192.168.42.10
      netmask 255.255.255.0
  ```
- `ifup usb0` fails with -

  > Cannot find device "usb0"
  >   Failed to bring up usb0.
- `ifconfig usb0` doesn't find the device
- `dmesg|grep usb0` gives me

  ```
  rndis_host 4-1.1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1, RNDIS device, ee:00:...
  ```

I tried a reboot, which didn't help, but produced another strange effect: `eth0` didn't start via the network manager. I had to put it in `/etc/network/interfaces` to get my network up.

Related or a different phenomenon?

Any hints on how to narrow where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:  It's been an [predictable network interface name](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) issue, renaming usb0 to something weird. Why this happend all of a sudden after years? I don't know. Maybe for the first time the USB connection was aready established while booting, so the system decided to behave like a multi-netinterface machine?

Anyhow, the problem is solved.